# Flutter app fails to build on iOS with FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller error

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm encountering an issue while trying to build my Flutter app on iOS. Strangely, all my previous projects are running without any problem, but newly created projects are not working at all. The issue persists both on the simulator and physical devices. I even tried pushing a test version on TestFlight, but it didn't work either.

When I attempt to build the app for iOS, I receive the following message in the console:

```
[VERBOSE-2:FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(35)] Using the Impeller rendering backend.
Lost connection to device.
Exited
```

Flutter Doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm64, locale en-TR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.80.0)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

I've searched for solutions, but couldn't find any that address this specific error. I'm unsure what might be causing this problem and how to resolve it.

I have tried the following steps to troubleshoot the issue, but they didn't resolve the problem:

- Restarting my machine.
- Updating Flutter to the latest version.
- Cleaning and rebuilding the project.
- Creating a new Flutter project and testing it, but the issue persists.

If anyone has experienced a similar problem or has any suggestions on how to resolve this issue, I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my app, this comes from Easy Localization and the update solved my problem. So You can try to check dependencies because you can't see any log about it